# How to link a Python project to a WSGI file?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, web.py

I want to link my Python project to a `wsgi` file. I am using `mod_wsgi`.

I would like my Python project to be located in `/var/www/myProject/start.py`.

I've configured Apache as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.me
    ServerAlias example.me
    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/documents
    LogLevel warn

    Alias /robots.txt /usr/local/www/documents/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.png /usr/local/www/documents/favicon.png
    Alias /media/ /usr/local/www/documents/media/

    <Directory /usr/local/www/documents>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myApp.wsgi

    <Directory /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So far this is what I have in `myApp.wsgi` file:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/.*', 'hello',
)

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world"

application = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
```

What do I have to do in order to link my project which is located in `/var/www/myProject/start.py` to be called by `myApp.wsgi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace final argument to WSGIScriptAlias with '/var/www/myProject/start.py'.

Change reference in Directory directive to '/var/www/myProject'. In other words, just set the configuration to point to the correct location in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have start.py in a different directory which you want to invoke from wsgi.py.

- In this case, you need to somehow tell wsgi.py to be able to import a module from a different folder.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder) has some details on that.

A better way will be to have wsgi file in the same folder as the start.py, and just import and load the application from there.. something like:

```
import start
start.load_application()
```